# How to add unescaped HTML-HREFs to a surefire-report to show links in Jenkins

Tags: java, html, surefire

My problem is as described in the title. I'd like to add an HREF into the output of a surefire-report. But surefire is escaping the `<`.

Does anyone know how to avoid the escaping?

Comment: did you try `&lt;` instead of `<`?

Answer (score 1):

The surefire-report is XML, right? If you want to embed HTML such as an href tag into an XML document, you have two choices:

1. Escape it as follows: `&lt;a href=\&quot;http://www.stackoverflow.com\&quot;/&gt;`
2. Use a CDATA section, remembering to escape the `]]>` bit of course!

Comment: I am almost positive that this is the answer.  It is the only one that makes sense.

Comment: It didn't work that way, but lead me to the solution I was looking for. The in 1. described solution leads to escaped `<` in the surefire-report too. As the URL is then simply written and interpreted I saw in the Jenkins-Report that if you use URLs like `http://www.stackoverflow.com` they are shown as links in Jenkins anyway. That was too simple. :)